# How to differentiate assigned roles vs mapped roles?

Tags: keycloak

I'm new to Keycloak and use it to map roles to users who are authenticated by an external IdP.
To map roles from this external IdP at every login, I've configured an *External role to role* protocol mapper on my identity provider with the *Sync mode override* set to *Force*.
Thus, in Keycloak, a user may have a role assigned manually (let's say `ROLE_A`) and a role mapped by the protocol mapper (let's say `ROLE_B`).
Everything works as expected: when the user is authenticated, `ROLE_B` is mapped or unmapped according to the user's roles at the external IdP.
However, if I modify the protocol mapper (for instance to map a different role named `ROLE_C` instead of `ROLE_B`), `ROLE_B` may remained permanently assigned to the user.

To tackle this problem, I'd like to replace the built-in *External role to role* mapper by a custom one that would clear any mapped role before mapping roles from the external IdP.

So my question is: how to remove all mapped roles (`ROLE_B`, `ROLE_C`) without removing roles that could have been manually assigned (`ROLE_A`)?
I cannot rely on prefixes since the same role could be manually assigned and mapped (in this case, I don't want to clear that role).